# Un-subset a dataset to model data another way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, subset

I want to run my analysis based on one subset of data, then re-run my analysis on another subset of data all coming from the same dataframe.

I have a dataset of survey responses. For simplification, it looks something like this:

| responseID | indvsignup | famsignup | type | usage | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | annual | yes | 56 |
| 1 | 9 | 1 | monthly | yes | 19 |
| 2 | 1 | NaN | monthly | no | 26 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | annual | no | 19 |
| 3 | 8 | NaN | annual | yes | 35 |
| 3 | 1 | 8 | monthly | no | 39 |

First, I want to model my data for individual membership signups.

```
model = smf.mixedlm("indvsignup ~ C(type) + C(usage) + age)",
df,
groups= "ResponseId").fit()

model.summary()
```

Second, I want to re-run this model based on a subset of monthly types. I sorted the data to keep rows where the value is monthly.

```
model = smf.mixedlm("indvsignup ~ C(usage) + age)",
df,
groups= "ResponseId").fit()

model.summary()
```

Then, I want to run the initial model again but for famsignup. To do this, I want to subset the data so that only rows with non-missing values in the family memberships signups column are used for the model

```
model = smf.mixedlm("famsignup ~ C(type) + C(usage) + age)",
df,
groups= "ResponseId").fit()

model.summary()
```

I figured it would be inefficient to re-import the dataframe and subset the data each time I want to rerun the analysis. What's a more efficient way to repeat different versions of an analysis from various subsets of the data?

I'm fairly new to Python, so my instinct is to re-import each time or create new notebooks for each specific analysis.

Comment: How are you doing the subsetting?  Most commands like this return a new dataframe with your subset, leaving the original alone.

Comment: @TimRoberts I was planning to use drop...What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Well, that CAN be the right way, but it's hard to know without more details.  In many cases, it's better to create a new structure that keeps only the ones you want (and that would let you keep the original), but as with so many things, it depends on the data.